# R loop for multiple VARs

Tags: r, loops, var

I have an R loop:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  VAR(reg_full,p = i, type = "both")
}
```

but when I run it I get no output (no error either). The console is simply waiting for my next output.

My goal is to run 10 different VAR models with lags 1 through 10, and then plot their IRFs using the `IRF` function of `vars` package. I am stuck on step one (calculate the VARs).

`p=i` is the lag selection that I would like in the model, ideally `i` takes the values 1:10. `reg_full` is my dataframe, `type = "both"` is just an option (not important).

Also, how do I assign a model name, such as `model1` to the model so that I store the results. The results are stored in a list object?

Thank you all for your efforts.

Comment: `lapply(1:10, function(i) VAR(reg_full, p=i, type="both"))`

Comment: Just do `mylist <- list()` before the loop and then inside the loop `mylist[[i]] <- ...`.

Comment: lapply is an excellent response as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
L <- list()
for(i in 1:10){
  L[[i]] <- VAR(reg_full,p = i, type = "both")
}
```

You can access each individual model with `L[[i]]`, for example the first model with `L[[1]]`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed for the VARs. Now I have to figure out how to plot the IRFs (getting errors so far)

Comment: When I try to access the elements of the list to plot the IRFs I get the following error:   Error in chol.default(sigma.u) : 
  the leading minor of order 4 is not positive definite                                                      eventhough the model is correct. When I run the model manually it plots just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @DM That is an other question (not related to your original question).